# How to find all textual files regardless of extension that contains only commas and digits?

Tags: java, python, search, powershell, grep

I have to search for files that may have any extension name. The special attribute that all these files have is that they are less than five lines long(less than 4 \n\r) and other than the line breaks, all characters are digits, spaces and commas. How would I write code that searches for files based on their content?

I am well aware this will take a long time to run.

My project does not require Java or Python, I simply mentioned them as I'm more familiar with them. Powershell is a worthy suggestion.

I am running a Windows 7 system.

Comment: Does your project require java or python?  If not, you should consider using shell tools (e.g. bash on linux or powershell on windows).

Comment: The problem here is that file extension sometimes can help imply the encoding, and these concepts of digits, commas and spaces mean nothing without reference to an encoding.

Comment: Can you give us more info? are these files in a unix-based filesystem, are you planning to use just java?

Comment: @David Good point, I was not aware of other tools like powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```py
valid_chars = set('0123456789, \r\n')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(root, fname)
        with open(fpath, 'rb') as f:
            lines = []
            for i, line in enumerate(f):
                if i >= 5 or not all(c in valid_chars for c in line):
                    break
            else:
                print 'found file: ' + fpath
```

Instead of `not all(c in valid_chars for c in line)`, you could use regular expressions:

```py
            ...
                if i >= 5 or not re.match(r'[\d, \r\n]*$', line):
            ...
```

If you go with regex, to improve efficiency use `re.compile` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

expected_chars = set(' ,1234567890\n\r')
nlines = 5
max_file_size = 1000  # ignore file longer than 1000bytes, this will speed things up


def process_dir(out, dirname, fnames):
    for fname in fnames:
    fpath = os.path.join(dirname, fname)

    if os.path.isfile(fpath):

        statinfo = os.stat(fpath)

        if statinfo.st_size < max_file_size: 
            with open(fpath) as f:
                # read the first n lines
                firstn = [ f.readline() for _ in range(nlines)]

                # if there are any more lines left this is not our file
                if f.readline():
                    continue

                # if the first n lines contain only spaces, commas, digits and new lines
                # this is our kind of file add it to the results.
                if not set(''.join(firstn)) - expected_chars:
                    out.append(fpath)


out = []
path.walk("/some/path/", process_dir, out)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `grep -r` and `-l` options. The `-r` allows you to search recursively in a directory over all the files and `-l` prints only the names of the files whose content matches your regex.

```
grep -r -l '\A([0-9, ]+\s){1,4}[0-9, ]+\Z' directory
```

This would print the list of names of all files that have less than 5 lines of numbers, space or comma characters.

The \A and \Z would check at the beginning and ending of the subject text. `[0-9, ]+` looks for a sequence of digits, spaces or commas followed by `\s` which is either a line break, space or a carriage return. This sequence can be repeated up to 4 times represented by `{1,4}` followed by another line of data.

Comment: I guess I could use grep from git bash. I suppose you should mention that would only work from *nix bash (not cmd or powershell) btw, could you please comment on the regex? I understand \d is digits(?) and , is comma. +s is a line break?

Answer (score 0):

In Python (I'll only outline the steps so you can program it yourself. But of course feel free to ask if you step into problems):

- Use [`os.path.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk) to find all files (it gives you all files, regardless of their extension).
- Note that it also gives you directories etc, so use [`os.path.isfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to skip them.
- For each file:

  - Open it ([`open`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)). Do the following inside a [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement to avoid having to close the file by hand.
  - You could first count the lines, then check for the comma thing, but that's probably slower, so:
  - Read the file line by line. For each line, do two things:
  - Count the lines. If you arrive at 5, go on with the next file.
  - Check if it matches the comma criterion. I'd use a [`regular expression`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for that. If it does not match, continue.
  - If you are at the end of the file, you were successful, so you can print the filename or whatever you want to do.